# ElasticSearch nested document search with AND operator

Tags: elasticsearch, nested

[Here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-nested-type.html) it is stated in nested documents, without using `nested query` it is not possible to retrieve document which satisfies multiple conditions at the same time through nested document's fields. [Here](http://www.spacevatican.org/2012/6/3/fun-with-elasticsearch-s-children-and-nested-documents/) also another explanation with example at beginning. Why does not it retrieve the only doc which satisfies all conditions?

Answer (score 0):

if you need multiple conditions with nested queries, why not to use `bool` query or `bool` filtered query?

Comment: Nested query works, since it is already designed for nested documents. I was curious about why standard query does not work.